# PHP Multiple variables in hyperlink

Tags: php

I want to add "max=<?php echo $row_select['max_price'] in hyperlink below, so that when the link's clicked, I can get both min and max price. Please advise how should the code be. Thank you.

Code in page 1

```
<a href="page2.php? min=<?php echo $row_select['min_price']; ?>">Price</a></td>
```

In page 2, my code to get min_price is as follows. It works. But I need to bring in max_price from page 1 as well.

```
$min_price = $_GET['min_price'];
<h2><?php echo $min_price; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try code below:

```
<a href="page2.php?min_price=<?php echo $row_select['min_price']; ?>&max_price=<?php echo $row_select['max_price']; ?>">Price</a></td>


$min_price = $_GET['min_price'];
$max_price = $_GET['max_price'];
<h2><?php echo $min_price; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $max_price; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate multiple query parameters with `&`.

```
<a href="page2.php?min=<?php echo $row_select['min_price']; ?>&max=<?php echo $row_select['max_price']; ?>">Price</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Always use urlencode for query string values
<a href="page2.php?min=<?=urlencode($row_select['min_price'])?>&max=<?=urlencode($row_select['max_price'])?>">Price</a></td>
```

Or:

```
// http_build_query doesn't require urlencode (it encodes values automatically)
<a href="page2.php?<?=http_build_query([
    'min' => $row_select['min_price'],
    'max' => $row_select['max_price'],
])?>">Price</a></td>
```

And for reading:

```
<?php
// Use ?? to prevent "variable is undefined" error (operator ?? is available since php 7.0)
$min_price = $_GET['min_price'] ?? 0;
$max_price = $_GET['max_price'] ?? 0;
?>

// Always use htmlspecialchars to prevent XSS attack
<h2><?=htmlspecialchars($min_price)?>, <?=htmlspecialchars($max_price)?></h2>
```

Comment: Top two answers worked so I didn't try yours. But still want to thank you for your detailed explaination.